# Change the content of mail after sending it

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible that I can change the content of my mail after sending it? This functionality is possible in silverpop by the name of "movable ink". How can we make this happen in SFMC? Are Live image and live offers the best possible alternatives to it?

Thanks: Gaj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No email engine can change the content of any email after sending it, the only possiblity is if the email references images or content from external hosts, in which case you can change the content at the host without changing the email itself.

Further, links can be changed by looking at the tracking section and finding the email, then the link, and repointing it. Note that personalised URLs can only be repointed to a non-personalised URL.

Answer (score 0):

To update this answer as it comes up in Google searches. Images can be replaced in Marketing Cloud using the 'Replace' command in 'Email Studio > Content'. This replaces the asset but keeps the URL the same for deployed emails

[image: Replace image functionality within Salesforce Marketing Cloud]